# Odoo unknown currency_field 'currency_id'

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

In Odoo 9 community version, I added the following monetary field as a monetary amount via the web interface: res.partner.x_tablet_bail_amount.

It's working fine, but when installing any new module I get the following error and my module does not install.
Any help? thanks!

```
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 605, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 642, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 316, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 309, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 893, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 471, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 998, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 986, in _call_kw
    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 238, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 459, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(cr, uid, ids, self.button_install, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 238, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 533, in _button_immediate_function
    registry = openerp.modules.registry.RegistryManager.new(cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 385, in new
    openerp.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 283, in load_modules
    registry.setup_models(cr, partial=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 199, in setup_models
    model._setup_fields(cr, SUPERUSER_ID)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 238, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 342, in old_api
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py", line 3044, in _setup_fields
    field.setup_full(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/fields.py", line 476, in setup_full
    self._setup_regular_full(model)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/fields.py", line 1131, in _setup_regular_full
    "Field %s with unknown currency_field %r" % (self, self.currency_field)
AssertionError: Field res.partner.x_tablet_bail_amount with unknown currency_field 'currency_id'
```

Answer (score 1):

Fields of type `monetary` are using other fields to do some stuff like printing currency symbols in reports or the client. Per default `currency_id` is used ([Odoo Code](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/openerp/fields.py#L1134)) for that process, and as far as i know there is no `currency_id` defined on `res.partner`.

So maybe you should define it or get it as related field from another relation?

Comment: Thanks. However I double-checked and there is a currency_id defined on res.partner.

Comment: Pardon me, of course there is a field `currency_id` on `res.partner` (needed for debit and credit). OK, then the error message is a bit awkward. I have no idea, what is wrong :-/

Answer (score 1):

'currency_id' field is added to 'res.partner' model in the 'account' mudule, so you have to add 'account' to the list of dependencies in the manifest and then the monetary field would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

From [the source code](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/openerp/addons/base/res/res_partner.py#L182) it does *not* seem to be any `currency_id` field defined on `res.partner`.

However the field is indeed defined on [`res.company`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/openerp/addons/base/res/res_company.py#L77), which has a Many2One relationship with `res.partner`. I suppose `res.partner` is nothing but a kind of partially abstract class that needs to be extended for every type of partner within Odoo, including companies (only guessing here).

So Odoo is right when it spits

> Field res.partner.x_tablet_bail_amount with unknown currency_field
>   'currency_id'

because the field is *not* there, really.

What you could do is, instead of defining your custom field `x_tablet_bail_amount` on `res.partner`, define it on `res.company`. That way your monetary field will be able to resolve the right currency instead of looking for something that does not exist.

Comment: But the field is there when searching for it in the UI (in database stucture). I don't know how odoo works, but is it possible that it's added later by a module? This could explain why it's not in the source code you point out. Moreover, there is only 1 company in my project and I need to define different values for custom field for all my customers, so I don't see how I could do this by defining x_tablet_bail_alount on res.company.
Reminder: res.company is the model for the company owning odoo, not for a customer (even when is_company=true for that customer).